# Android NDK build fails after adding FFmpeg with: error: cannot find -lnative

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

First of all, I'm fairly new to building native code on Android and C++ in general, so it's possible I am missing something very obvious to more seasonded developers...

I am working on an Android app that uses [Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe) for audio processing. So far this has all been working, I set up the NDK, added a CMakeLists.txt, compiled my code and ran the app, all fine.

Now I tried to integrate FFmpeg into my project following the steps described in this article: [Using FFmpeg for faster audio decoding](https://medium.com/@donturner/using-ffmpeg-for-faster-audio-decoding-967894e94e71). I compiled FFmpeg using the script provided there and moved the files to the mentioned folders. I made the changes to my CMakeList.txt to be able to use the compiled FFmpeg files, and the IDE sees everything just fine.

But my builds break with this error:

```
Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lnative
```

I've done some googleing and research on the issue but can't seem to figure it out. Not sure what exactly is missing here and where to get it...Any help is much appreciated!

Here's my CMakeList.txt

```
set(FFMPEG_DIR /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/${ANDROID_ABI})

include_directories(src/main/cpp/)
include_directories(native-lib ${FFMPEG_DIR}/include)

add_library(avformat SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
       ${FFMPEG_DIR}/lib/libavformat.so)
add_library(avutil SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avutil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
       ${FFMPEG_DIR}/lib/libavutil.so)
add_library(avcodec SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avcodec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
       ${FFMPEG_DIR}/lib/libavcodec.so)
add_library(swresample SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(swresample PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
       ${FFMPEG_DIR}/lib/libswresample.so)


add_library(native-lib

       SHARED

       src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
       src/main/cpp/AudioEngine.cpp
       src/main/cpp/DataSource.h
       src/main/cpp/StorageDataSource.cpp
       src/main/cpp/LockFreeQueue.h
       src/main/cpp/logging.h
       src/main/cpp/NDKExtractor.cpp
       src/main/cpp/Constants.h
       src/main/cpp/OpenGLFunctions.cpp
       src/main/cpp/Player.cpp
       src/main/cpp/Mixer.h
       src/main/cpp/IRenderableAudio.h
       src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp
       src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.h
       src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp
       )

set(TARGET_LIBS log android oboe GLESv2)

set(TARGET_LIBS ${TARGET_LIBS} native avformat avutil avcodec swresample)

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${TARGET_LIBS})

#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Set the path to the Oboe directory.
set(OBOE_DIR /Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/oboe-test/oboe)

# Add the Oboe library as a subdirectory.
add_subdirectory(${OBOE_DIR} ./oboe)


# Specify the path to the Oboe header files.
include_directories(${OBOE_DIR}/include)
```

And this is the end part of the native build task's log output (full log was too large to post):

```
Build native-lib_armeabi-v7a

(...)

[38/41] /Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -DOBOE_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp -I../../../../native-lib -I/volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/include -I/Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/oboe-test/oboe/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/Player.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/Player.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/Player.cpp.o -c /Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/MyApp/app/src/main/cpp/Player.cpp
[39/41] /Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -DOBOE_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp -I../../../../native-lib -I/volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/include -I/Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/oboe-test/oboe/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp.o -c /Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/MyApp/app/src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp
[40/41] /Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot  -DOBOE_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp -I../../../../native-lib -I/volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/include -I/Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/oboe-test/oboe/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp.o -c /Volumes/Work/Repos/Android/MyApp/app/src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp
[41/41] : && /Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/AudioEngine.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/StorageDataSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/NDKExtractor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/OpenGLFunctions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/Player.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp.o  -llog -landroid oboe/liboboe.a -lGLESv2 -lnative /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libavformat.so /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libavutil.so /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libavcodec.so /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libswresample.so -llog -lOpenSLES -latomic -lm && :
FAILED: : && /Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/AudioEngine.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/StorageDataSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/NDKExtractor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/OpenGLFunctions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/Player.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/UtilityFunctions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/FFMpegExtractor.cpp.o  -llog -landroid oboe/liboboe.a -lGLESv2 -lnative /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libavformat.so /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libavutil.so /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libavcodec.so /volumes/work/repos/android/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libswresample.so -llog -lOpenSLES -latomic -lm && :
/Users/myuserfolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lnative
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Why did you add `native` to that `target_link_libraries` statement? It is not in the article you linked nor defined in your CMake file.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't belong there, and it's also causing the error. Not sure how this ended up there, but when I remove it, everything works as intended. Thank you for pointing this out! Since it's a comment I can't mark this as the accepted answer though...